# Django-tables2 send parameters to custom table template

Tags: django, django-tables2

I'm trying to use a custom table template to embed the `django-filter` fields on my table. So I copied the `django-tables2` *bootstrap.html* template  in a new file *custom_table.html*. Then I added it the following code in the `thead` section:

```
     {% if filter %}
       <tr>
          {% for filter_field in filter.form.fields %}
              <td>
                 {{ filter_field }}
              </td>
          {% endfor %}
          <td>
             <button class="login100-form-btn" type="submit">Filter</button>
          </td>
       </tr>
    {% endif %}
```

So the problem is : how can I send the `filter` to the table template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue. I have overridden the `get_context_data` function of my view:

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
   
         context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
         table = self.get_table(**self.get_table_kwargs())
         table.filter = self.filterset
         context[self.get_context_table_name(table)] = table
         return context
```

In this way, I can use the filter in my custom table template by the following code:

```
               {% if table.filter %}

                <tr>
                    <form action="" method="get" class="form-inline">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {% for field_form in table.filter.form %}
                        <th>
                            {{field_form}}
                        </th>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <th>
                            <button class="btn" type="submit">Filter</button>
                        </th>
                    </form>
                </tr>
                {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send the `query paramters` to the server, and construct the table using **`filtered_queryset`**. For example:

```
#views.py
def your_view(request):
    filter = ModelFilter(request.GET, queryset=Model.objects.all())

    filtered_queryset = filter.qs
    # pass filtered_queryset to your table
    table = SimpleTable(filtered_queryset)
    return render(request, 'table.html', {'table': table})
```

Comment: thank you for answer. I want to insert the form filter field in the table, one for each column. The problem is how I can send the `filter` object to the custom template. Now I'm trying to build the form inside the template, but it would be easier using the filter form in the template